# How to fix "if statement" issue in my code?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Here is my code. I want P_ABP and P_ACP values to be zero if they are smaller than 0. But I still get negative values when I plot the graph.

```matlab
day = 40;
angle_mu = 8;
lat = 30.43;
Ps = 1000;
elev = 59.9;
time = linspace(0,24,24);
alpha = 360/24*(time-12);
dec = 23.44sind(360(day-80)/365.25);
zen = acosd(sind(dec).*sind(lat)+cosd(dec).*cosd(lat).*cosd(alpha));
tan_azi = atand(sind(alpha)./sind(lat).*cos(alpha)-cosd(lat).*tand(dec));
azi = atand(tan_azi);
for i = 1:length(alpha)
    if alpha(i) >=0 && tan_azi(i) >=0
       azi(i) = 180 + azi(i); 
    elseif alpha(i) >=0 && tan_azi(i) <=0
       azi(i) = 360 + azi(i); 
    elseif alpha(i) <=0 && tan_azi(i) >=0
       azi(i) = azi(i); 
    elseif alpha(i) <=0 && tan_azi(i) <=0
       azi(i) = 180 + azi(i); 
    end
end

A = 0.433*2;
surf_aziABP = 0;
surf_aziACP = 0;
P_ABP = 0;
P_ACP = 0;
rotation = linspace(1,8,24);
for a = 1:length(time)
    surf_aziABP = 60-angle_mu + (rotation(a).*time);
    surf_aziACP = 60+angle_mu + (rotation(a).*time);
    for b = 1:length(time)
        P_ABP = (Ps.*(cosd(elev).*cosd(zen)+sind(elev).*sind(zen).*cosd(azi- surf_aziABP(b))));  
        P_ACP = (Ps.*(cosd(elev).*cosd(zen)+sind(elev).*sind(zen).*cosd(azi- surf_aziACP(b)))); 
    end
end

if P_ABP < 0
   P_ABP = 0; 
elseif P_ACP < 0
   P_ACP = 0; 
end

Power_Total = P_ABP + P_ACP;
POW = A.*Power_Total;
plot(rotation,POW)
grid on
xlabel('Angular Velocity/Hour')
ylabel('Power (W/m^2')
sumPOW = sum(POW)
trapz(time,POW)
```

Comment: I’ve shown you how to get code formatted as code. Now please [edit] the post again and put back your indenting and so on. Code is hard to read without it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach may be done by setting the arrays `P_ABP` and `P_ACP` to zero by indexing the arrays based on the following condition **(Code Snippet)** below. This can reduce the need for looping and if-statements. I have also included a looping code snippet to run the if-statements across all the indices of the arrays if you prefer it to continue to use if-statements.

### Code Snippet:

```
P_ABP(P_ABP < 0) = 0;
P_ACP(P_ACP < 0) = 0;
```

**Alternatively by Loops and If-Statements:**

```
for Index = 1:length(P_ABP)

if P_ABP(1,Index) < 0
   P_ABP(1,Index) = 0; 
end
   
if P_ACP(1,Index) < 0
   P_ACP(1,Index) = 0; 
end
end
```

Another note is that the following line may have been missing multiplication operators:

**Original:**

```
dec = 23.44sind(360(day-80)/365.25);
```

**Modified:**

```
dec = 23.44*sind(360*(day-80)/365.25);
```

[image: Positive Only Plot]

### Full Script:

```
day = 40;
angle_mu = 8;
lat = 30.43;
Ps = 1000;
elev = 59.9;
time = linspace(0,24,24);

alpha = 360/24*(time-12);
dec = 23.44*sind(360*(day-80)/365.25);
zen = acosd(sind(dec).*sind(lat)+cosd(dec).*cosd(lat).*cosd(alpha));
tan_azi = atand(sind(alpha)./sind(lat).*cos(alpha)-cosd(lat).*tand(dec));
azi = atand(tan_azi);

for i = 1:length(alpha)

if alpha(i) >=0 && tan_azi(i) >=0
azi(i) = 180 + azi(i); 

elseif alpha(i) >=0 && tan_azi(i) <=0
azi(i) = 360 + azi(i); 

elseif alpha(i) <=0 && tan_azi(i) >=0
azi(i) = azi(i); 

elseif alpha(i) <=0 && tan_azi(i) <=0
azi(i) = 180 + azi(i); 

end

end

A = 0.433*2;
surf_aziABP = 0;
surf_aziACP = 0;

P_ABP = 0;
P_ACP = 0;

rotation = linspace(1,8,24);

for a = 1:length(time)

surf_aziABP = 60-angle_mu + (rotation(a).*time);
surf_aziACP = 60+angle_mu + (rotation(a).*time);

for b = 1:length(time)

P_ABP = (Ps.*(cosd(elev).*cosd(zen)+sind(elev).*sind(zen).*cosd(azi- surf_aziABP(b))));  
P_ACP = (Ps.*(cosd(elev).*cosd(zen)+sind(elev).*sind(zen).*cosd(azi- surf_aziACP(b)))); 

end
end

P_ABP(P_ABP < 0) = 0;
P_ACP(P_ACP < 0) = 0;

Power_Total = P_ABP + P_ACP;
POW = A.*Power_Total;
plot(rotation,POW)

grid on
xlabel('Angular Velocity/Hour'); ylabel('Power (W/m^2');
sumPOW = sum(POW);
trapz(time,POW);
```

Comment: Just to expand on the reason why OP's method was not working, both P_ABP and P_ACP are arrays, and thus the condition (P_* < 0) in the if statement only checks if every element in them respects the condition.